# Angular 6 injected service can't be resolved

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have built an Angular 6 library 'auth' with the two services `'./src/lib/auth.service.ts'` (AuthService) and `'./src/lib/error.service.ts'` (ErrorService).

Now i want to use both services in my Angular 6 app - both injected into another service like:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private errorService: ErrorService
  ) {}
```

But when i try to compile the app the following error occures:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'auth/lib/error.service' in 'C:\Projects\MyProject\src\app\services\data'
```

I can import the ErrorService without any problems and VSCode doesn't show any errors. Only whe  i try to compile it.

The Library and the app are built with the same versions of Angular 6.
I also added `error.service.ts` to `public_api.ts` and i provide it in `auth.module.ts`.

The `AuthModule` is imported into `app.module.ts`

```
...
import { AuthModule } from './auth';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [EditDialogComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  ...
}
```

Here is the file `public_api.ts`:

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of auth
 */

export * from './lib/auth.service';
export * from './lib/error.service';
export * from './lib/auth.component';
export * from './lib/auth.module';
```

And the file `error.service.ts` (still empty):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class ErrorService {

    }
```

I don't have any problems with the AuthService.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you build your library  before run ng serve?

Comment: Is it in the `providers` list of the correct relevant module ? is the module defining it imported ?

Comment: can you share your app.module.ts file

Comment: @miladfm yes i am runnung 'ng build auth --watch' - successful.

Comment: @Pac0 i provide the service in the module auf the library. The Library-Module is imported in app.module.ts

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal i have added the relevant parts of app.module.ts

Comment: @Daniel what's about my answer?

Comment: have you "exported" the auth.service and the error.service in the public_api ?  then you import should look like   import { ErrorService } from 'auth'

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal sorry my bad i have shortened the path and removed a scope cause i thought it was unnecessary

Comment: @xrobert35 but shouldn't it be enough to provide the service in the librarys module and import the module?

Comment: no  the module is just the angular context, you need also to export the file for compilation. Every service and component file should be exported if you "import them" , else you will have compilation failure

Comment: (it was a wrong comment to tell you to add './' since you are use a library ,  every import should look like  import { SOMETHING } from 'auth'  (auth will be resolved in the node_modules and since you tell in your package.json that public_api is the main file, and since you exported the elements everything should be resolved

Answer (score 1):

AuthService and ErrorService should initiate before your third service. so please provide them in app module(root), then they will be singleton.

as [this link](https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angular-3b253df5c21)

Comment: i have tried to provide it in app.module and now i see besides the old error a new error:
error TS2305: Module '"C:/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/auth/auth"' has no exported member 'ErrorService'.

But i export it in the public_api.ts... any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel can you please update your question with your `public_api.ts` and `error-service.ts` files?

Comment: this is an error about importing. can you show the app module please.